# Strange bug with fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have  some application which uses vertex and fragment shaders.

Some conditional logic is implemented in fragment shader. It is little more complicated as pass-through shader.

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 pass_Top_Color;
in vec3 pass_Bottom_Color;
in vec3 pass_Single_Color;

uniform float singleColor;
uniform float topOnly;
uniform float bottomOnly;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) 
{
    if (singleColor > 0.5)
    {        
     if (topOnly > 0.5)
     {
            out_Color = vec4(pass_Top_Color, 1.0);        
     }
     else if (bottomOnly > 0.5)
     {
            out_Color = vec4(pass_Bottom_Color, 1.0);   
     }
     else
     {
            out_Color = vec4(pass_Single_Color, 1.0);
     }
    }
}
```

My video card (AMD Radeon HD 6450) works normally and supports OpenGL 4.4.

But when I try to draw with this shader as output I get only empty screen. Any errors occurred.

For test, I use `VAO` where only `in_Single_Color` attribute is used. Before drawing I setup `singleColor` uniform to `1.0f` so `if (singleColor > 0.5)` condition is true. Corresponding to normal logic, everything have to be OK (but it doesn't - as result only clear screen).

But when I comment part of shader (as below). Everything works nice. Really strange that when I move this application (with not commented code in shader) to another PC it works nice.

```
 #version 150 core

    in vec3 pass_Top_Color;
    in vec3 pass_Bottom_Color;
    in vec3 pass_Single_Color;

    uniform float singleColor;
    uniform float topOnly;
    uniform float bottomOnly;

    out vec4 out_Color;

    void main(void) 
    {
        if (singleColor > 0.5)
        {
         //if (topOnly > 0.5)
         //{
         //     out_Color = vec4(pass_Top_Color, 1.0);        
         //}
         //else if (bottomOnly > 0.5)
         //{
         //     out_Color = vec4(pass_Bottom_Color, 1.0);   
         //}
         //else
         //{
                out_Color = vec4(pass_Single_Color, 1.0);
         //}
        }
    }
```

Hope for help with such bizarre effects.

Comment: You should assign some color to out_Color if the outer if-statement is false. I.e, when singleColor is less than 0.5. My guess is that singleColor actually is less than 0.5 and that you are not setting the uniform correctly in your OpenGL code.

Comment: heh, I wrote about strange bug because I actually set singleColor uniform to 1.0 in inner code. And really strange that lower code is correctly works on most of PCs where I tried it except one :)